# Value type 'System.Data.DataRow' cannot converted to 'datatype'

Tags: vb.net

I'm following a book provided by our school, and that book doesn't address errors so I don't know how to approach this(and our teacher just says to follow the book). Anyway, conversion of data types seem to have a problem, I also tried `Cstr` and the others and yielded the same result. I also decided `Option Strict Off` as the codes provided exploded with errors, as of now this class is the only problem and after this the app should start working.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class clsBookDA
Private Shared dcnBooks As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\books.mdb")

Private Shared books As New ArrayList()

Private Shared aBook As clsBook
Private Shared aBookID, anAuthor, aTitle As String
Private Shared aPurchasePrice, aSalePrice As Decimal
Private Shared anInventory As Integer

Public Shared Sub Initialize()
    dcnBooks.Open()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Terminate()
    dcnBooks.Close()
    dcnBooks.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetAll() As ArrayList
    Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dtbBooks As New DataTable()
    Dim drwBook As DataRow()

    dapBooks = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Books", dcnBooks)
    dapBooks.Fill(dtbBooks)

    books.Clear()
    For Each drwBook In dtbBooks.Rows
        aBookID = drwBook("BookID") 'error converting to string'
        anAuthor = drwBook("Author") 'error converting to string'
        aTitle = drwBook("Title") 'error converting to string'
        aPurchasePrice = drwBook("PurchasePrice") 'error converting to decimal'
        aSalePrice = drwBook("SalePrice") 'error converting to decimal'
        anInventory = drwBook("Inventory") 'error converting to integer'
        Dim aBook As New clsBook(aBookID, anAuthor, aTitle, aPurchasePrice, aSalePrice, anInventory)
        books.Add(aBook)
    Next
    Return books
End Function

Public Shared Sub Add(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
    Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Books" & "VALUES ('" & _
        aBook.aBookID & "','" & aBook.Author & "','" & aBook.Title & "','" & _
        aBook.PurchasePrice & "','" & aBook.SalePrice & "','" & _
        aBook.Inventory & "')"

    dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
    dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Update(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
    Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE Books" & "SET Author = '" & _
        aBook.Author & "',Title ='" & aBook.Title & "',PurchasePrice='" & _
        aBook.PurchasePrice & "',SalePrice='" & aBook.SalePrice & _
        "',Inventory='" & aBook.Inventory & "'" & _
        "WHERE BookID='" & aBook.BookID & "'"

    dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
    dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Delete(ByVal aBook As clsBook)
    Dim dapBooks As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE BookID = '" & _
        aBook.BookID & "'"

    dapBooks.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dcnBooks)
    dapBooks.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Private Shared Function Author() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

Private Shared Function BookID() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: You are referencing the DataRow class not the value stored in the DB, so you ca not convert to the System Type. Your column heading can be used in drwBook.item("heading") Ref:
Item[DataColumn] 
Gets or sets the data stored in the specified DataColumn. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-5.0

Comment: I tried to do Dim drwBook as DataColumn but when, I tried to do this 'drwBook.Item("heading")' it said that item is not part of the System.Array

Answer (score 0):

Option Strict On won't complain if you cast these things from Object (what theyre stored as) to their actual type (stored inside an Object):

```
    For Each drwBook In dtbBooks.Rows
        aBookID = DirectCast(drwBook("BookID"), String)
        anAuthor = DirectCast(drwBook("Author"), String)
        aTitle = DirectCast(drwBook("Title"), String)
        aPurchasePrice = DirectCast(drwBook("PurchasePrice"), Decimal)
        aSalePrice = DirectCast(drwBook("SalePrice"), Decimal)
        anInventory = DirectCast(drwBook("Inventory"), Integer)
        Dim aBook As New clsBook(aBookID, anAuthor, aTitle, aPurchasePrice, aSalePrice, anInventory)
        books.Add(aBook)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conversion functions like drwBook("BookID").tostring()